# What's the adj and adv form for 'quality'?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering if *qualitative* and *qualitatively* is the adj and adv forms of quality? According to [the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quality), *quality* itself can also be adjective.

> 10. of high quality -- *quality goods*

It seems to me that quality and qualitative mean differently when being adjective.

Another dictionary on my phone says there is no comparative or superlative form for the adjective word - *quality*. Is it true? If yes, why?

Comment: The adjective is quality: quality products are hard to find. Qualitative is not the adjective here. [qualitative is opposed to quantitative]. Quality, the adjective is opposed to junk, for example.

Comment: I've found "How are we going to best provide **the most quality** care for the most number of people, as opposed to just allowing systems to go unchecked..." in [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), and I think in that sentence *the most quality* is a superlative.

Comment: most quality care is not great. The "greatest quality of care" would be better. Most quality care is substandard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quality: Quality products. OK.

High quality products become: higher (or better) quality products or higher (or better) quality of product,  lower quality products or lower quality of product, the best quality products or the best quality of product; the worst quality products or the worst quality of product; the lowest quality products or the lower quality of product.

That is how to do the comparative. This is just like the comparatives for words like expensive. Many adjectives with two or more syllables. That's how you do it.

for adjectives of three or more syllables: expensive, inexpensive, illustrious, crushing, etc. Those are just examples that would follow this pattern.

Comment: The way we do comparative for three or more syllables is that we use *more*, such as more expensive. But do we say *more quality* in this case?

Comment: No, you cannot use more. If I say: more quality products, it means greater numbers of them. In the singular, it is plain wrong: a higher quality of product or: These products are higher quality products than those products. These products are a higher quality of product than those. Is it clear  now?